# Связанные select jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть три условных двумерных массивa:

```
arrayMerged1 = {
        {value: "1", text: "10"} 
        {value: "2", text: "14"} 
        {value: "3", text: "27"} 
    }

arrayMerged2 = {
        {value: "21", text: "08-12Х18Н10Т"} 
        {value: "52", text: "40Х"} 
        {value: "36", text: "09Г2С"} 
    }

arrayMerged3 = {
        {value: "5", text: "1.5"} 
        {value: "10", text: "2.5"} 
        {value: "7", text: "4"} 
    }
```

Так же есть три, несвязанных между собой **select**, **value** и **text** у них тот же самый. У первого **select** данные из **arrayMerged1** и так далее.

Данные массивов были взяты из таблицы ниже:

[image: таблица]

Так как эта таблица сделана через представление в Drupal 7, то у каждого **tr** и **td** есть свои классы, из-за чего к ним можно легко обратиться в скрипте.

Мне предстоит сделать эти **select** связанными между собой, но я не могу понять, как мне построить логику в скрипте. Другими словами, каким образом при выборе значения в первом **select**, скрипт будет понимать, какие значения нужно оставить во втором? Так же у меня нет возможности использовать jQuery плагин **Chained Selects**

Comment: Ничего непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот один из способов "синхронизировать" значения в `select`.

```js
$('.sync').on('change', syncSelects);

function syncSelects() {
  var that = this;
  $('.sync').each(function() {
    if (this !== that) {
      this.selectedIndex = that.selectedIndex;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sync'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class='sync'>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select class='sync'>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
</select>
```